# How to Over ride youtube external style?

Tags: css, youtube, youtube-api, overriding, external

I'm working on a website and i use a wordpress plug-in that embeds youtube videos.

Now it has this great option to show only an image of the video and load the video only if you press the video so the page won't take a lot of time to load.

The problem is that in that mode it takes that video photo from youtube and it also takes a big, red, play button image that is ugly as hell :)

Now that button's css is coming from some external link (http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflSBO3VV.css) and i don't know how to over ride it.

Any suggestions?

That is the site i'm working on btw - http://www.lab.gezerweb.com/ClipPress/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're talking about an embed that uses `controls=2`, correct? (See https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls)

If so, then no, there's no way to override the default play button in the cued state.